# Inserting data into table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know if it's possible to insert data into a table variable from a select query. When using a variable table before I have inserted the values and typed them myself.

I have come up with the following select query that displays the latest comment for a repair order. It returns 37 records and I wanted to know if it's possible to insert those into a variable table.

```
SELECT 
    a.CH_REPREF, a.CH_DATE, a.CH_CRTIME,
    b.[Latest Customer Comment], a.CH_CRUSER, a.CH_CCOMMNT
FROM 
   (SELECT 
        CH_REPREF, 
        MAX(CH_REPREF1) As [Latest Customer Comment]
    FROM 
        dbo.V_CSRPCH
    WHERE 
        CH_CCOMMNT IS NOT NULL 
        AND CH_CCOMMNT NOT LIKE 'X'
    GROUP BY 
        CH_REPREF) b,
   (SELECT 
        CH_REPREF, CH_DATE, CH_CRTIME, CH_REPREF1, 
        CH_CRUSER, CH_CCOMMNT, CH_ACCOUNT
    FROM 
        dbo.V_CSRPCH) a
WHERE 
    CH_REPREF1 = [Latest Customer Comment] 
    AND CH_ACCOUNT = 'DDCHC'
```

I have started the table variable with the following, but am stuck whether it's possible to fill it with the data returned by the select query:

```
Declare @tbl_last_customer_comment TABLE
(CH_REPREF nvarchar(10),
CH_DATE smalldatetime,
CH_CRTIME nvarchar(8),
Latest int,
CH_CRUSER nvarchar(8),
CH_CCOMMNT text)
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO @tbl_last_customer_comment  SELECT ...`

Comment: `INSERT INTO @table_variable (column_1, column_2, etc) SELECT column_1, column_2, etc FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

just do it as 'constant' table-

```
INSERT INTO @tbl_last_customer_comment
SELECT a.CH_REPREF, a.CH_DATE, a.CH_CRTIME,b.[Latest Customer Comment],a.CH_CRUSER,a.CH_CCOMMNT
FROM (SELECT CH_REPREF, MAX(CH_REPREF1) As [Latest Customer Comment]
FROM dbo.V_CSRPCH
WHERE CH_CCOMMNT IS Not Null AND CH_CCOMMNT Not Like 'X'
GROUP BY CH_REPREF) b,
(SELECT CH_REPREF, CH_DATE, CH_CRTIME,CH_REPREF1, CH_CRUSER, CH_CCOMMNT, CH_ACCOUNT
FROM dbo.V_CSRPCH) a
WHERE CH_REPREF1 = [Latest Customer Comment] AND CH_ACCOUNT = 'DDCHC'
```